# SSRS dynamic XML datasource connection string possible?

Tags: xml, reporting-services, datasource

I'd like to have a dynamic XML datasource in my reporting services.
So far, the following works (Setting in the 'manage datasource' of SSRS 2016):

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/data-connections-data-sources-and-connection-strings-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017#bkmk_Expressions_in_connection_strings) paragraph, but no luck.

Connection type : `XML`

Connection string :
`http://192.168.1.0/reports/generate.xml?reporting_token=XXXXXX`

Now I have several environments. Currently for every environment I have a separate datasource, each of which has its equal reports. In order to avoid this, a single dynamic XML datasource would be very handy.

I added the parameter `ServerName` to the report using this datasource, and changed the above config to:

`=Parameters!ServerName.Value + "/reports/generate.xml?reporting_token=XXXXXX"`

But getting the error **Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.**

When checking my app log, I see the the server part of the string is not in:

`Started POST "/reports/generate.xml?reporting_token=XXXXXX`

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Use a textbox to view the expression output. Maybe its because of missing http://

Comment: Thanks niktrs. I have done the test; the server string arrives properly in the report.
I have doubts that my intention is even supported by SSRS..